# C struct compound initialization without setting everything to zero

Tags: c, syntax

Is there any syntax similar to doing something like this

```
typedef struct foo
{
   int X;
   int Y;
   int Z;
} foo;

int main()
{
   // Initialize everything
   foo Variable = (foo){
    .X = 10;
    .Y = 15;
    .Z = 20;
   };

  // Assign the X and Y variables, but keep Z the same
  Variable = (foo){
   .X = 15;
   .Y = 20;
  // .Z stays the same
  };
}
```

Would be nice to have this type of QOL syntax instead of  having to type

```
int main()
{
   foo Variable = {bla bla};

   // Keep having to type Variable. to access struct members
   Variable.X = 10;
   Variable.Y = 15;
}
```

This gets really annoying with structs in structs i.e.

```
Struct1->Struct2.Struct3.Element.X = 10;
Struct1->Struct2.Struct3.Element.Y = 15;
```

Comment: @pmg Yeah it should be "assign these variables" I'll fix that

Comment: Make a function (or several): `void setXY(struct foo *bar, int x, int y) { bar->X = x; bar->Y = y; }`

Comment: `This gets really annoying with structs in structs i.e.` So use a variable: `TYPE* something = &Struct1->Struct2.Struct3.Element; something->X = 10; something->Y = 15;`

Answer (score 2):

No, C does not support this style of initialization or assignment.

If you want to access only a part of a structure, you need to express this explicitely.

**EDIT:**

You can get away with:

```c
    Variable = (foo){
       .X = 15;
       .Y = 20;
       .Z = Variable.Z;
    };
```

At least an optimizing compiler will just generate the operations for the changing elements. But it is more source than single assignments.

Comment: noooo my typing fingers :(

Comment: @Nates3 What's your problem exactly?

Comment: @Zakk My question is about whether or not you can set values of groups of members from an already initialized structure so you don't have to keep typing the variable names every single time.

Comment: @Nates3 Use a decent IDE, get used to use its suggestions, and a lot of burden is taken away from you. ;-) Remember, source is read by factors more than written, and it should express your intent explicitely and on the first sight in the context of its programming language. The less magic, the better. The compiler is "just" the final translator into the target's language, the real recipients of source are future developers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the preprocessor to save your fingers (or copy/paste)...

```
    struct {
        int f1;
        int f2;
        struct {
            int b1;
            int b2;
            int b3;
        } bar;
    } foo = {
        1, 2, { 42, 43, 44 },
    };

    printf( "%d  %d  %d\n", foo.bar.b1, foo.bar.b2, foo.bar.b3 );
#define S foo.bar
    S.b1 = 7;
    S.b2 = 8;
    printf( "%d  %d  %d\n", S.b1, S.b2, S.b3 );
#undef S
```